cannot install latest mysqlclient on ubuntu
I have read pip install mysql-python fails with EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found and mysql_config not found when installing mysqldb python interface and I am sure it is not a duplicate question.
I had run sudo apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential pkg-config and I have those build tools. I have mariadb installed. I also tried a different pypi mirror and the issue presists.
Now I tried pip install mysqlclient and I got this. It seemed that pip is trying through versions. Finally I installed version 2.1.1
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/pypi/web/packages/7d/62/51fbcd851834c830c940ded80280f593bd031137603329dd89479c68c5be/mysqlclient-2.2.6.tar.gz (91 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
  WARNING: Generating metadata for package mysqlclient produced metadata for project name unknown. Fix your #egg=mysqlclient fragments.
Discarding https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/pypi/web/packages/7d/62/51fbcd851834c830c940ded80280f593bd031137603329dd89479c68c5be/mysqlclient-2.2.6.tar.gz#sha256=c0b46d9b78b461dbb62482089ca8040fa916595b1b30f831ebbd1b0a82b43d53 (from https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/pypi/web/simple/mysqlclient/) (requires-python:>=3.8): Requested unknown from https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/pypi/web/packages/7d/62/51fbcd851834c830c940ded80280f593bd031137603329dd89479c68c5be/mysqlclient-2.2.6.tar.gz#sha256=c0b46d9b78b461dbb62482089ca8040fa916595b1b30f831ebbd1b0a82b43d53 has inconsistent name: filename has 'mysqlclient', but metadata has 'unknown'
  Using cached https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/pypi/web/packages/be/95/1af2ee813d4f0b607082c18bb82aa05c98a95a402a1d2d5808999317cb16/mysqlclient-2.2.5.tar.gz (90 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
  WARNING: Generating metadata for package mysqlclient produced metadata for project name unknown. Fix your #egg=mysqlclient fragments.
Discarding https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/pypi/web/packages/be/95/1af2ee813d4f0b607082c18bb82aa05c98a95a402a1d2d5808999317cb16/mysqlclient-2.2.5.tar.gz#sha256=add8643c32f738014d252d2bdebb478623b04802e8396d5903905db36474d3ff (from https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/pypi/web/simple/mysqlclient/) (requires-python:>=3.8): Requested unknown from https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/pypi/web/packages/be/95/1af2ee813d4f0b607082c18bb82aa05c98a95a402a1d2d5808999317cb16/mysqlclient-2.2.5.tar.gz#sha256=add8643c32f738014d252d2bdebb478623b04802e8396d5903905db36474d3ff has inconsistent name: filename has 'mysqlclient', but metadata has 'unknown'
  Using cached https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/pypi/web/packages/79/33/996dc0ba3f03e2399adc91a7de1f61cb14b57ebdb4cc6eca8a78723043cb/mysqlclient-2.2.4.tar.gz (90 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... -^canceled
ERROR: Operation cancelled by user

My system is Linux VM-16-16-ubuntu 5.15.0-124-generic #134-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 27 20:20:17 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
My python version is Python 3.10.12

This question might better fit on https://askubuntu.com/. Please add your Ubuntu version number.

Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS 64bit

Please [edit] your question to add requested infromation or clarification. I suggest to ask your question on askubuntu.com. By starting to [edit] your question here you can get the markdown source code you can use to write the same question on the other site. Afterwards delete it here. Please also explain in your question why you need the latest version. As you use a LTS version of Ubuntu and even an older LTS version, you should expect to get more stable software packages instead of the latest ones.

thank you. Now I know that the latest package may not be available for my version of ubuntu

Thanks to @bodo,Now I know that though I can install the package onto windows, but my ubuntu may not support the latest version. I never knew that before
